# Magento UPC API

Tags: api, magento

What is the Array options for Products.update?  I need to add UPC information to all of my products and I want to build a script to perform this task:

```
$client->call($session, 'catalog_product.update', array($product['sku'], 'upc'=>$xml));
```

Its not working because I don't know the UPC - XML=>UPC equivalent.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If indeed your custom attribute code is 'ups', then you need to do the following:

```
$client->call($session, 'catalog_product.update', array($product['sku'], array('upc' => $xml)));
```

There was an error with your code.  You need to send the upc in an array, which you were not declaring.  I assume your $xml is the upc value for the product?